# Choosing Windows File Open and File Save Dialogs - What is the Best Practice?

Tags: windows, file-io, dialog

For some time I've noticed how much the File Open and File save dialogs vary between Windows itself and Applications. In Delphi for example (which I use) you can use the built-in dialogs (which have a folder tree) and direct calls to the Windows API which produce variants of the Windows version, with or without large buttons for 'Desktop', 'My Computer' etc (At least on XP).

As an application developer I'm interested in providing the User with a clean, simple way of loading and saving files. Typically, this requires that I propose a preferred folder where my Application data files are stored but that I allow the User to access other folders - often the desktop and other local drives, and sometimes the network - without difficulty if required.

With the introduction of Vista, we seem to be favouring a 'bits missing' folder navigation tree for Windows dialogs and now, Windows 7 has another 'line-less tree' for navigation. I suspect that if one conforms to Microsofts assumptions and stores everything in ~/documents it's not a big problem. However, if one has to start at the root of a drives tree and there are many directories then it's a right pain - there is no horizontal scrolling so directory names get truncated.

My question is - what do other Application developers use? I wonder whether I should be following this Windows lead or simply sticking to a simple cut-down version of File dialogs over which I full control but risk falling into the past....?

Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use the OS defaults - it'll be what your users are used to, and what they expect. Whatever you do, [don't astonish the user](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Whatever you do, please don't write your own file-open/file-save dialog.

FWIW, I'm not a great fan of Vista's file-open dialog (why do I have to work so hard to navigate my folders?), but I'd rather that than have to get to grips with something new. The less things your users have to learn, the easier your product is to use.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am currently only coding for customers with Windows XP (in a corporate environment that isn't upgrading just yet) I use the standard dialog boxes.

When we do upgrade, I will most likely continue to use the standard old fashioned dialog boxes, until our customers are ready for a change.

In all honesty, I involve at least a few users in the development process, and I won't start new features unless I can bring one in to sit in front of my development PC to see how it works, and they sign off on it.

For those apps that we write for our web site, we tend to be conservative as well... Focus on clean, understandable design, and introduce fancy new features only when there is a compelling reason, and even then, we tend to involve focus groups.

So all that was a long way of saying "Ask your customers".  Give them what they want.

Comment: I lean toward this, but I know that that will lead to us providing 'XP'-style File Open/Save dialogs even on Vista/W7. Our particular Users are VERY conservative but they do accept new things if you hand them over with a good reason. Brian.